# SQL : Delete And Insert In One Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-delete

I want delete query execute only once in the beginning. After that execution of insert statement, until the all data successfully saved in DB.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database?? SQL is just the **query language** used by many database systems - but those are all slightly different in how they handle stuff - especially things like stored procedures. Please add a relevant tag (`oracle`,. `mysql`, `sql-server`, `db2`, `postgresql`) to your questions!

Answer (score 1):

Try using MERGE statement

-- MERGE statement with the join conditions specified correctly.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S

ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

Comment: i want to perform delete and insert on single table. First Delete all the row from table1 and then execute insert

Comment: Merge will take care of that. Whatever you want to insert put it in a temp table and treat it as Source and the table you want to update as Target. So if you will put 3 rows in temp table (source table) it will insert those three rows and will delete rest in the target table